# OpenLayers create marker (feature with icon) from WKT

Tags: openlayers-2, javascript, features, well-known-text

I have a point object WKT. Like this: `POINT (25.04568 48.221548)`. Also I have an icon in my project folder.

My goal is to show on a map **an icon** that represents a feature. Can it be just a normal OpenLayers feature (if yes, then how can I define that it should represent and icon) or do I need to create an OpenLayers marker (somehow create `LonLat` from WKT)?

Comment: I have tried to fix typos and grammar to make sense of the title and the question but I just could not understand your first parenthetical remark "if yes,...." Could you please edit it to make it meaningful?

Comment: edited, it is better?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change icons for all objects on map, you can change the style. For example:

```
testLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("testLayer", {
      rendererOptions: { zIndexing: true },
      styleMap: new OpenLayers.StyleMap({
          "default": new OpenLayers.Style({
              externalGraphic: "../../pics/icon1.png",
              graphicWidth:32,
              graphicHeight:34,
              graphicXOffset:-10,
              graphicYOffset:-34  ,
              graphicZIndex: 1
          }, 
          OpenLayers.Feature.Vector.style["default"]),
          "select": new OpenLayers.Style({
              externalGraphic: "../../pics/icon2.png",
              graphicWidth:36,
              graphicHeight:38,
              graphicXOffset:-12,
              graphicYOffset:-38,
              graphicZIndex: 1000
          })
      })
```

If you want to set icon for one object, you can use OpenLayers.Marker. But it is not recommended. For example:

```
        function addNewMarkers() {
            ...
        var position = map.getLonLatFromPixel(e.xy);
        var size = new OpenLayers.Size(21,25);

    var offset = new OpenLayers.Pixel(-(size.w/2), -size.h);
    var icon = new OpenLayers.Icon('OpenLayers-2.12/img/marker-gold.png', size, offset);

    var markersLayer = map.getLayer('Markers');
        var myTestMarker = new OpenLayers.Marker(position,icon);
            ...
            markersLayer.addMarker(myTestMarker);
       }
```